# Error loading backoffice content tree in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

My umbraco backoffice application is not loading the content tree all of the sudden. I can't figure what I would have done to make this stop working.

When I open backoffice, a request to the following URL is failing
umbraco/UmbracoTrees/ApplicationTree/GetApplicationTrees?application=content&tree=&isDialog=false

This is the message that's coming back:
)]}',
{"tree.String":"A value is required but was not present in the request."}

I don't have a lot to work with here... I've tried deleting cookies and rebuilding the app but I'm not having any luck. I really need to get this working ASAP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was...

I added a filter to the HttpConfiguration on start up and it make BackOffice quit working. The filter simply validated any models passed to WebAPI. Oh well, I don't really have time to look into anymore so I'm just not going to use the filter...